# Need server side endpoints for doing transactions with recurly

Tags: server-side, recurly

I was trying to integrate recurly with my application after i got my token id, i need to the recurly endpoints so that i can use my token id and complete the transaction.

Can someone help me with the available API operations with recurly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rama - take a look at docs.recurly.com. Under our developer documentation, you'll see the endpoint URLs above api code examples.